# How to adjust SSE or RMSE for the number of free parameters in the model?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, computational-modeling, statistics

How do I adjust SSE (sum of squared errors) or RMSE ([root-mean-square errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation)) for the number of free parameters in the model?

Is there an "adjusted" RMSD metric similar to the [adjusted r-squared metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2)?

Comment: please don't assume that we know what RMSD stands for. The more effort you invest in carefully phrasing your question, the more motivated people will feel to answer it.

Comment: This sounds more like a question better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/ . Is there an aspect of this that relates particularly to cognitive modelling?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean by "adjusted" here ? Do you mean adjusted as for "goodness of fit" or as correction in regards to some parameters ?

Comment: @Cheatboy2 I believe he is referring to a correction in the number of parameters, as in adjusted $r^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to discount SSE (or RMSE) by the number of free params:

$$
\text{adjusted RMSE} = \sqrt{\frac{SSE}{n - k}}
$$

$$
AIC = n \times ln\left(\frac{SSE}{n}\right) - k \times ln(n)
$$

$$
BIC = n \times ln\left(\frac{SSE}{n}\right) - 2 \times k
$$

or in computer code style:

```
k = number of free params
n = number of DV's
SSE = sum of squared errors

adjusted RMSE = sqrt ( SSE / n - k )
AIC = n * ln(SSE/n) - k * ln(n)
BIC = n * ln(SSE/n) - 2 * k
```

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, there is no adjusted RMSD.

RMSD, unlike $R^2$, isn't typically used to compare models across the literature. $R^2$ represents the proportion of variance explained by the model, a construct which translates well across different experimental designs. Adjusted $R^2$ distorts this by accounting for the number of parameters in your model, but is a better estimate of the proportion of variance in the *population* explained by your model.

RMSD is in whatever units you happen to be using. It should be interpreted against some benchmark for what you think a good model should be, or whatever has been deemed an "acceptable error rate". It's not clear to me that adjusting for the number of parameters in RMSD would provide a number that is inherently meaningful, but I'm not sure if this is true.

If you would like to select among several model candidates, you may want to compute [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) (Akaike Information Criterion) or [BIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) (Bayesian Information Criterion), both of which are attempts to maximize the likelihood of your model while minimizing the number of parameters. Both metrics are commonly used in cognitive modeling, and I think this may be what you are looking for.

While I think this question is on-topic here, you will likely get better answers on [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com) (as Jeromy points out) because your question is not really specific to *cognitive* modeling.